# What word means 'unremembered?'

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Like when a person has little to no presence?

You notice him or her but is easily forgotten?

Comment: Probably 'unmemorable'

Comment: Please show us how you would like to use it in a sentence.

Comment: This question is nondescript. ;)

Comment: Perhaps an "insignificant person" or an "everyman figure".

Answer (score 4):

The word I would choose for this is:

**Forgettable** : likely to be forgotten : not worth remembering

Edit: Just realized you said easily forgotten in your question, so you may have already thought of it, but it's my favorite word to describe someone that no one ever remembers.

Answer (score 0):

"Unremarkable.".

(The OP requires a single word. This parenthetical comment is to satisfy the requirement that the post has minimum length.)